# Angular 8 ngFor's keyvalue pipe and ngModels. Having issues binding values

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get this component working that will take an object of key/value pairs, display them in input tags, and change them on the original object. So say I have an object like:

```
{
    name: "John",
    id: "12345",
    preferences: { foo: "bar", biz: "baz" }
}
```

I can call `<key-value [obj]="profile.preferences"></key-value>` and the data will be printed in two pairs in input tags. If I then changed "foo" to "qux" the property key would change. To accomplish this I have a key-value component that really simply does:

```
<div *ngFor="let pref of obj | keyvalue">
     <input [(ngModel)]="pref.key"><br />
     <input [(ngModel)]="pref.value"><br />
</div>
```

Which I feel is very simple. It's an object passed in, so it's a reference to the original object, and the ngModels in literally every other input of my application work so I assume that's not wrong.

I've done a lot of looking around and I did actually get it working if I had a "changeKey/changeValue" function that would change this.obj in the component rather than relying on binding:

```
<div *ngFor="let pref of obj | keyvalue">
     <input (change)="changeKey(/*???*/)" [ngModel]="pref.key"><br />
     <input (change)="changeValue(pref.key, pref.value) [ngModel]="pref.value"><br />
</div>
```

That works for the changeValue because I have the key I need to change and the new value. But the issue with the changeKey is because pref.key has been changed I don't know which key to update.

I feel like this shouldn't be that difficult, I'm still quite new to Angular and I'm hoping someone here knows what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `I don't know which key to update`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the `changeKey` function like the following code.

In Component

```
changeKey(prevKey, newKey) {
  const value = this.obj[prevKey];
  delete this.obj[prevKey];
  this.obj[newKey] = value;
}
```

In HTML

```
<input (change)="changeKey(pref.key, $event.target.value)" [ngModel]="pref.key"><br />
```

I created [a working example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8jtjjv).

Comment: is this keyvalue pipe Angular 8 feature? or from which version is it available

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar Added in 6.1 I believe.

Comment: Also, $event.target.value. Thank you. I tried passing in event but I couldn't find the value, leading me to think I couldn't find it there. That's exactly what I wanted, thank you.

Answer (score 11):

[KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#description) in a nutshell:

> Transforms Object or Map into an array of key value pairs.

The `keyvalue` pipe creates a **new** array from a given object, and as such, binding to it will not affect the original object.

As for your issue, instead of using the `(change)` event listener, you can bind `ngModel` to your original object and point to it directly:

```
<div *ngFor="let prop of myObject | keyvalue">
      <input [(ngModel)]="myObject[prop.key]">
</div>
```

Comment: works, but leads to a loose of focus of the input field after every key press

Comment: Hi @wutzebaer, are you using any additional UI frameworks within your project? I can't reproduce the behaviour you're describing. Thx

Comment: I am getting Type 'unknown' cannot be used as an index type.

Comment: Hey @user1689987, this error occurs when a value that is possibly `unknown` is used to index an object or array. To solve the error, try using a type guard to ensure the value is not `unknown` before indexing the object.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do it like this for example:

```
 <span *ngIf="hasProp(subChart.series, 'params')" >
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" *ngFor="let keyVal of subChart.series.params |  keyvalue">
          <mat-label>{{keyVal.key}}</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="number" [(ngModel)]="subChart.series.params[castToString(keyVal.key)]"
                 [value]="subChart.series.params[castToString(keyVal.key)]" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </span>
```

Which uses these functions:

```
  public castToString(obj: any): string{
    return obj as string;
  }
  public hasProp(obj: any, name: string) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(name);
  }
```